# IndexError: index 232 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 232 based on List with different length

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a dictionary called my_Dict which have some keys called column Name and some values (Lists). The keys of the dictionary have the same name than some of the pandas DataFrame columns Name

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for k, v in df.iteritems():
    for i in range (len(df.index.values)):
         df[k][i]=my_Dict[k][i]
```

I have this error:`IndexError: index 232 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 232`

How can I ensure that my List always have the same size (size of the dictionary values (List) with maximum lenght?

Comment: Is your code correct ? Where is `Dict` and `List` variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Remember: `tab[0] -> size = 1`, so `tab[232] -> size = 233`

Not quite sure what your question means but:
To ensure that your list is always the same size, you'll have to add some verifications, there's no other choice or modify your previous algorithms that will, while filling the List, assures it respects an accorded size.
If length of List != length of Dict then do something.

Comment: What if i add, may be nan when the index becomes out of bound?